# Web-Worker with GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, web, web-worker

What's the simplest way of getting a Web-Worker thread loaded with a GWT module?

I am not referring to getting support for Web-Worker in GWT (there are libraries for that) but rather how would generate a GWT module for loading into a web-worker?

I suspect I need a special Linker - is there one available somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/speedtracer/source/browse/trunk/src/client/ui/src/com/google/gwt/webworker/
I didn't dig deep but it seems to be that "special linker" you're looking for (the linker is then used for the "hintlet engine" and "breaky" modules of SpeedTracer)

Answer (score 4):

There is a library called gwt-ns which includes web worker.
Following link is the example using it.
http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=645

**UPDATE**
The author of gwt-ns posted a note that he stopped development since 2010, so it's not compatible with recent GWT (like 2.6.1 or later)

> NOTE (04 February 2014): gwt-ns hasn't been touched since June 2010
>   and my understanding is that the Web Worker support does not work in
>   any recent versions of GWT. This is somewhat expected, as it had to
>   reach fairly far into the GWT compiler to work and would have had to
>   make changes as the compiler design changed.
>        The other modules are also likely out of date since permutation selection for these features would need to be adjusted as browsers add
>   support or move support from prefixed to full. Some things might still
>   accidentally work.
>        Feel free to use the code as you please, but be forewarned. I no longer do any GWT development, so if you'd like to get workers working
>   again with gwt-ns as a base, you'll need to fork the code and start a
>   new project (luckily the Apache 2.0 license makes this easy for you).

Comment: Unfortunately, gwt-ns project was only compatible with GWT 2.0-2.2

Answer (score 2):

You can try my [gwtwwlinker](https://github.com/tomekziel/gwtwwlinker) project published on GitHub: https://github.com/tomekziel/gwtwwlinker

It allows you to compile separate module as web worker, dedicated linker eliminates usual `$wnd` and `$doc` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Manfred Tremmel has taken the core code from the Google Speedtest application and put it in a separate repository [gwt-webworker](https://gitlab.com/ManfredTremmel/gwt-webworker/). I've added a very simple example code at [SimpleWebWorker](https://github.com/RichardMorris/SimpleGWTWebWorker). This code works with the latest 2.8.1 version of GWT.